# Is there is a option of replicating a line and making multiple cursor in anaconda ide?

Tags: anaconda, ide

Is there is a option of copying a same line and making multiple cursor in anaconda ide?

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate line:** A rapid triple click on a line, followed by `cmd c`, then `cmd v` will copy/paste the line.

**Multiple cursor**s can be set with `cmd click`, and unset with a `click`

if windows: replace `cmd` with `ctrl`